# SetupDLL to remove a folder and a key register

Tags: .net-3.5, compact-framework, setup-project, cab, windows-mobile-6

Develop an application on Compact Framework. net 3.5 c# for Windows Mobile 6.x.

In uninstalling the application would like to remove some keys in the register and a folder with its contents.

Searching the internet I met other tips on how to use the SetupDLL Cab project and discovered that I have to create a c + + project, implement the methods

**Install_Init** - called before installation begins.

**Install_Exit** - called after an application is installed.

**Uninstall_Init** - called before an application is uninstalled.

**Uninstall_Exit** - called after an application is uninstalled.

as described in the link:
http://www.christec.co.nz/blog/archives/119

Well my great difficulty is to remove a folder and all its contents and delete a key in the register using c++.

I've tried several methods to find on the internet but none even compiles.

Please, now more than 3 days I'm still unable to solve this problem.

**Sample method in C++ to delete recursive directory:**

```
    bool RemoveDirectory(string path) {
    if (path[path.length()-1] != '\\') path += "\\";
    // first off, we need to create a pointer to a directory
    DIR *pdir = NULL; // remember, it's good practice to initialise a pointer to NULL!
    pdir = opendir (path.c_str());
    struct dirent *pent = NULL;
    if (pdir == NULL) { // if pdir wasn't initialised correctly
        return false; // return false to say "we couldn't do it"
    } // end if
    char file[256];

    int counter = 1; // use this to skip the first TWO which cause an infinite loop (and eventually, stack overflow)
    while (pent = readdir (pdir)) { // while there is still something in the directory to list
        if (counter > 2) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) file[i] = '\0';
            strcat(file, path.c_str());
            if (pent == NULL) { // if pent has not been initialised correctly
                return false; // we couldn't do it
            } // otherwise, it was initialised correctly, so let's delete the file~
            strcat(file, pent->d_name); // concatenate the strings to get the complete path
            if (IsDirectory(file) == true) {
                RemoveDirectory(file);
            } else { // it's a file, we can use remove
                remove(file);
            }
        } counter++;
    }

    // finally, let's clean up
    closedir (pdir); // close the directory
    if (!rmdir(path.c_str())) return false; // delete the directory
    return true;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The big problem with what I'm seeing in your code is that it's all ASCII (char, strcat, etc) and CE uses Unicode.  I also don't fully understand your passing of things like a "string" type - you must be importing some things that aren't shown.

What you really need is to call [FindFirstFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms889678.aspx) in your path, then iteratively call [DeleteFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms889001.aspx) and [FindNextFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms889873.aspx) until there are no more files.  Once the folder is empty, call [RemoveDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms891470.aspx).

[This implementation](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/files/deletedir.aspx) looks reasonable (though the "IsDots" stuff can be omitted for CE).

**EDIT**
Turns out that the implementation linked above has a bug when actually used in a Unicode environment.  I've fixed it as well as made it compatible for CE (while maintaining desktop compatibility).  Here's teh updated version:

```
BOOL DeleteDirectory(TCHAR* sPath) {
   HANDLE hFind;    // file handle
   WIN32_FIND_DATA FindFileData;

   TCHAR DirPath[MAX_PATH];
   TCHAR FileName[MAX_PATH];

   _tcscpy(DirPath, sPath);
   _tcscat(DirPath, _T("\\*"));    // searching all files
   _tcscpy(FileName, sPath);
   _tcscat(FileName, _T("\\"));

   // find the first file
   hFind = FindFirstFile(DirPath,&FindFileData);
   if(hFind == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) return FALSE;
   _tcscpy(DirPath,FileName);

   bool bSearch = true;
   while(bSearch) {    // until we find an entry
      if(FindNextFile(hFind,&FindFileData)) {
         _tcscat(FileName,FindFileData.cFileName);
         if((FindFileData.dwFileAttributes &
            FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)) {

            // we have found a directory, recurse
            if(!DeleteDirectory(FileName)) {
                FindClose(hFind);
                return FALSE;    // directory couldn't be deleted
            }
            // remove the empty directory
            RemoveDirectory(FileName);
             _tcscpy(FileName,DirPath);
         }
         else {
            if(FindFileData.dwFileAttributes &
               FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY)
                SetFileAttributes(FindFileData.cFileName, 
                    FindFileData.dwFileAttributes & ~FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY);
                  if(!DeleteFile(FileName)) {    // delete the file
                    FindClose(hFind);
                    return FALSE;
               }
               _tcscpy(FileName,DirPath);
         }
      }
      else {
         // no more files there
         if(GetLastError() == ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES)
         bSearch = false;
         else {
            // some error occurred; close the handle and return FALSE
               FindClose(hFind);
               return FALSE;
         }

      }

   }
   FindClose(hFind);                  // close the file handle

   return RemoveDirectory(sPath);     // remove the empty directory
}
```

Comment: **When I copy and paste the code, the following errors:**

Error 10 error C2664: 'wcscat' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'const char [3]' to 'const wchar_t *' 

Error 11 error C2664: 'wcscat' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'const char [2]' to 'const wchar_t *' 

Error 12 error C3861: 'IsDots': identifier not found 

Error 13 error C2065: '_S_IWRITE' : undeclared identifier 

Error 14 error C3861: '_chmod': identifier not found
_Please, I know nothing about c++,_

Comment: Thank you so much!  
Solved my problem now is compiling, I test to see if it will remove  the folder.
But I believe it will work.  

Now we need to remove a key from the register

Comment: How can I call this function?
I'm trying with the command: DeleteDirectory ("\Temp\Test");
but it is giving the error:
warning C4129: 'T': unrecognized character escape sequence
warning C4129: 'T': unrecognized character escape sequence
error C3861: 'deleteDirectory': identifier not found

Comment: DeleteDirectory(_T("\\temp\\test"));

Comment: Sorry it bothers you so much, but the compiler does not find the function.

Comment: What function are you talking about?  DeleteDirectory is the function you're working on; the source code is above.

Comment: Please don't edit my answer.  It confuses things when the person asking the question starts making edits to an answer.  Your specific problem now is most that you don't have a forward delcaration for the DeleteDirectory function.  Move it above the Uninstall_Exit function.

Comment: Sorry, this is my first question in Stack Overflow.   Will test and return